# aiogram 3 skip_update

Tags: python, aiogram

Начал впитывать в себя aiogram 3, и столкнулся с проблемой, в старых версиях библиотеки был фильтр как `skip_update=True/False` (в случае отключения бота, при повторном включении этот фильтр не давал боту обрабатывать сообщения которые были отправлены в момент его нерабочего состояния)
Старая версия кода выглядела так:

```
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.run_polling(bot, skip_update=True)
"""
```

В текущей версии aiogram код выглядит так:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.run_polling(bot, ???)
```

Но в нем не хватает одной детали... Я обшастал пару ресурсов, но ничего не нашел!
Подскажите пожалуйста как это поправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение данной проблемы:

```
from aiogram.methods import DeleteWebhook

async def main():
    await bot(DeleteWebhook(drop_pending_updates=True))
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
```